# Import huge mysql database to access

Tags: mysql, sql, database, odbc

I have a problem with importing a huge Database to Access.
I have created a ODBC Connection and selected the database in access.

The Database has 5 Tables the biggest Table has about 9 mio records.

The import of the smallest 2 Tables work's fine. (About 600k and 1 mio records).

In the ODBC Database configuration i have set the setting "Allow Big data result" and "Don't cache results of forward-only cursors".

But the import of the big Tables fail with message `odbc call failed`. I have no idea, how to solve the problem?

Comment: Why import this many records into an inferior tool for large data sets like Access?  The best solution I can come up with for you is don't do whatever you're trying to do in Access if you have above 10k records.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this help you out . 
Click Last record as soon as the table is opened in order to display all records in the linked table in the Datasheet View of Access .
Do not select all records in the linked table to be displayed. Instead, select only a limited number of records.
also you can look here for more details. [Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6b9761bb-f195-446b-94c2-a77a87201487/odbccall-failed-access?forum=sqldataaccess)